# Google Drive API v3 cannot find file although file existed on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Someone shared with me a folder. This folder exist under "Shared With Me" section. Let's named it "SF1"(Shared Folder 1).
This folder contains sub-folders in the first level. Let's named it "SUB1" (Sub-Folder 1)
The folder SUB1 contains images that i want to download.
I have wrote a code that works normal but under one condition. The condition is that i have to access (preview) the file from Google Drive Page. For example lets suppose that the SUB1 contains 20 images. For the code below the Google Drive will return 1 file.

```
FileListRequest.PageSize = 10;
FileListRequest.Q = "parents in 'GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID'";
FileListRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
```

The reson after a lot of search is simple. It returns always the first file that exists in SUB1. It assumes that i have "access" it.

If i make i "Preview" for the next lets say 10 files, the same code will return me **11 images** that exist in this directory although that exists 20 images.

Note that the directory details is the "master" search. If i change it based to file type eg

```
FileListRequest.Q = "mimeType = 'image/jpeg' and parents in 'GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID'";
```

or even

```
FileListRequest.Q = "mimeType = 'image/jpeg'";
```

the result is the same. If i will not make an action with the file, the API doesn't recognize it. It "not exists" for API.
Even i try to retrieve it via name only:

```
FileListRequest.Q = "name = 'sample-photo.jpg'";
```

But in case that i will make an action with 'sample-photo.jpg' eg Preview from Google Drive Page, the API will return me the file with the same code that before didn't return me anything.

Is there a parameter that i have to assign/declare? Is it a bug of API? The privileges that i have to this folder that is shared wih me is only View and download **not edit/upload**.

Comment: Can I ask you about the scopes you are using?

Comment: `GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID` is the Id of `SF1`?  Is `SUB1` explicitely shared with you?

Comment: GOOGLE_FOLDER_ID is the id for the SUB1. I'm having the same behaviour even with the id of SF1

Comment: The scope that i'using is DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly

Comment: This behavior is strange. I am wondering if the files are corrupt and are not considered `image/jpeg` until you preview them. Can you see any change in the file after you preview it?